# Node.js application with Heroku Scheduler having a Shebang line issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, shebang

I am trying to deploy a small Node.js application to Heroku, and then have the Heroku Scheduler run the application every 10 minutes. Our customers former supplier who built this application also hosted it on Heroku, so there should be no need to change anything in the sourcecode, that I have received. Nevertheless I am getting the following error from the Heroku log.

```
2018-05-09T07:26:07.710882+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `fetch` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2018-05-09T07:26:11.124833+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2653]: Starting process with command `fetch`
2018-05-09T07:26:11.718182+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2653]: State changed from starting to up
2018-05-09T07:26:13.647479+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2653]: State changed from up to complete
2018-05-09T07:26:13.629258+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2653]: Process exited with status 126
2018-05-09T07:26:13.542885+00:00 app[scheduler.2653]: bash: /app/bin/fetch: /usr/local/bin/node: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Apparently there's an issue with the 'Shebang' line in my `fetch` file which runs my `index.js` file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
var path = require('path');
require(path.join(__dirname, '../index')).start();
```

I am rather new to Node.js and Javascript, so I'm not sure I fully understand the purpose of the 'Shebang' line. But I'm guessing it is pointing to a wrong location or something like that? How do I figure out, what to change in this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shebang line tells which interpreter to use to run the file. Error you receive tells that node is not installed in location shebang points to. Using `#!/usr/bin/env node` usually works.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a need for any "shebang" line in your "fetch" file.
I suggest you simply remove the `#!/usr/local/bin/node` line, and specify the following as your Heroku Scheduler command:

```
node <path_to_fetch.js>
```

That should get heroku scheduler to launch your node.js app in a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos), provided you have a [node.js buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) in your app.

Use the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to check if you have a node.js buildpack in your app, and to add it if necessary.

That said, if you really want to run your app with a "shebang", change it to `#!/usr/bin/env node`. In that case, omit the word `node` in your Heroku scheduler command.